# Buy 1 get 1 free or buy 2 get 1 free in Zen Cart

Tags: zen-cart

How do I add a sales section, buy 1 get 1 free or buy 2 get 1 free or buy 3 get 1 free, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a built in, but it seems to be provided by this module.  I can't speak for the security of the module of course, and I've never personally used it.

http://www.thatsoftwareguy.com/zencart_better_together.html

Comment: I am already using this but its not fulfilled my requirement.Is there any other plugin for this.?

Comment: In what way is it lacking?  From the website: "How about buy one product 2, get one free?"

   function setup() { 
      $this->add_prod_to_prod(2,2,"%", 100); 
   }

Comment: Admin user cannot change the values in admin side.

Comment: There's a panel for that: http://www.thatsoftwareguy.com/zencart_better_together_admin.html